# Rails 3 Observer -- looking to learn how to implement an Observer for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

I'd like to add an Auditor Observer which does an action anytime after_create for 3 models (books, characters, authors)...

I recently heard of the Observer capability but can't find any documentation on the ability. Is it support in Rails 3?

How do I create an Auditor Observer that does something after_create for 3 models?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add this around line 25 of your application.rb `config.active_record.observers = :auditor_observer`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Rails [observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Observer.html) are sweet, You can `observe` multiple models within a single **observer**

First, you need to generate your observer:

```
rails g observer Auditor
```

Then, in your fresh auditor_observer.rb file define the models you wish to `observe` and then add the `after_create` callback.

```
 class AuditorObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   observe :model_foo, :model_bar, :model_baz

   def after_create(record)
    #do something with `record`
   end
 end
```

In application.rb add

```
config.active_record.observers = :auditor_observer
```

And It should work.

Comment: Strange, for some reason it's not working. I added a debugger logger and nothing's getting written. Is there some other step required to get the Observer to kick in?

Comment: K turns out it needs to be "ActiveRecord::Observer" and it needs to be defined in the application.rb file in the config directory.

Comment: You can leave off "Observer" in the class name of the generate script: "rails g observer Auditor" generates AuditorObserver.