# Write a global method that sets created_by and updated_by by current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All models in my project have created_by and updated_by. Created_by is set by current_user on create and updated_by is set by current_user on update. Is there a way to write one global method to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a gem that does it - https://github.com/house9/clerk

It is not very configurable at this time

- your database columns must be named created_by_id and updated_by_id on your database tables

Checkout the README for more information

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it globally would be to implement `ActiveRecord::Observer`. An observer can 'observe' multiple models at a time and check for their life cycle callbacks. So in your observer you would specify what all models to observe and define `after_create` and `after_update` methods to perform whatever updates you want in your database.

Please refer [Rails 3 Observer -- looking to learn how to implement an Observer for multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826260/rails-3-observer-looking-to-learn-how-to-implement-an-observer-for-multiple-m) .

Comment: But wont that lead to TWO save requests made to database? E.g. First save is whatever had to be saved. Second is to save created_by and updated_by. Right?